# Update by query Elasticsearch-PHP Client 2.0+

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using `Elasticsearch 2.1.1` php client for my ES operations. I want to update my docs by query. For that I found [updatebyquery](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) but this is not working for `2.0+ versions` of ES. So is there any new way for updating my docs by query?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with **updateByQuery** as well, have a look at [this quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156405/update-by-query-updatebyquery-elasticsearch-php/39162965#39162965)

First you need to edit your `elasticsearch.yml` to allow Scripting. Append the following lines at the end.

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on
```

Then construct a query that will update all your records that match your conditions.

```
$client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['127.0.0.1:9200'])->build();
    # Request
    $updateRequest = [
        'index'     => 'testindex',
        'type'      => 'logs',
        'conflicts' => 'proceed',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [ 
                'filtered' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        'bool' =>   [
                                        'must' =>
                                        [
                                            [
                                                'match' => [ 'enabled' => 1 ],
                                            ],
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
            'script' => [
                    'inline' => 'ctx._source.enabled = value',
                    'params' => [
                        'value' => 0
                    ]
            ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    # Update 
    $results = $client->updateByQuery($updateRequest);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13470862)

Comment: (To whoever down voted) Please give a reason to why you downvoted this answer. If my answer does not work i will be happy to fix it or maybe elaborate more. Otherwise i think the answer deserves an up vote to help other people who are stuck just like i was.