# _update_by_query in elasticserach-php client

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 6.2 with [elasticsearch-php](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html) 6.0 client. There is situation i got stuck. I need to update field `userid` = 987 where `userid` = 123. I went through [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html), Here in every query we need to pass document ID in `API` (like `POST test/_doc/1/_update`). First i need to fetch `_id` and then i have to make update query with `POST test/_doc/{_id}/_update`

It won't possible to every time produce `_id`. It didn't help me.
 
I found another option to use [_update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html). In which i got success by using following API:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_update_by_query?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
   "query":{
      "term":{
         "userid":123
      }
   },
   "script":{
      "lang":"painless",
      "inline":"ctx._source.userid = params.value",
      "params":{
         "value":987
      }
   }
}'
```

I am not finding any reference which shows how i can use `_update_by_query` with elasticserach-php client. Plus let me know if you guyz have better way to tackle this. Thanks!

Comment: I think that elasticsearch-php client use here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_updating_documents.html update_by_query, anyway I think that can solve your problem

Comment: @Averias Please read carefully i already mention that link in my question.

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood it, sorry. In that case take a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156405/update-by-query-updatebyquery-elasticsearch-php/39162965#39162965 probably it can help you

Comment: @Averias Already tried before posting this question its using Elasticsearch 2.3 . I want to know about elasticserach 6.x

Comment: Looking at elasticsearch-php documentation for version 6.0, it seems they don't still provide anything regarding `update_by_query`, but I think the link above is still useful using es-php 6.0. In version 2.x `update_by_query` was a plugin you should install on your cluster, but the query in the example can be still used, probably you don't have to touch `elasticsearch.yml` since in versions 6 is a built-in feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution So i would like to share:

```
$client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['127.0.0.1:9200'])->build();
$update = [
    'index'     => 'my_index',
    'type'      => 'my_type',
    'conflicts' => 'proceed',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'term' => [
                    "userid" => 987
            ]
        ],
        'script' => [
            'lang' => 'painless',
            'inline' => 'ctx._source.userid = params.userid',
                'params' => [
                    'userid' => 123
                ]
            ]
    ]
];
$results = $client->updateByQuery($update);
```

It solve my problem. I think elasticserach should document this.

Comment: I'm pretty glad my suggestions definitively help you to solve your problem. IMHO `ruflin/elastica` is better PHP package to deal with ES https://packagist.org/packages/ruflin/elastica

Comment: Doesn't `'conflicts' => 'proceed'` mean that if there is a version conflict the update will not be made?