# What is the best way to push/add new elements into a nested array of objects in ElasticSearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a candidate Index where documents are structured like so :

```
{
  "_index" : "candidates",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "a23OcncBXBMGOH6pwXge",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 1,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "id" : "413",
    "firstname" : "Tania",
    "lastname" : "Stroman",
    "email" : "Berlin@yahoo.com",
    "zip" : "60306",
    "city" : "frankfurt",
    "birthday" : "1978-11-22",
    "tags" : [
      "php",
      "munich"
    ],
    "location" : {
      "lat" : 50.11601257324219,
      "lon" : 8.669955253601074
    }
  }
}
```

Once a candidate uploads their file, If it's the first uploaded file, I add a field called 'file' to the elastic document. If there are uploaded files in the document already, I push the subsequent uploads to the existing array with the following code :

```
public function attachCandidateFile($file)
    {
        $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();

        $params = [
            'index' => 'candidates',
            'id'    => $file['candidate_id']
        ];

        $candidate = $client->get($params);

        if (!is_array($candidate['_source']['file'])) {
            $candidate['_source']['file'] = [];
        } 
        array_push($candidate['_source']['file'], $file);

        $params = [
            'index' => 'candidates',
            'type'  => '_doc',
            'id'    =>  $file['candidate_id'],   
            'body'  => [
                'doc' => [
                    'file' => $candidate['_source']['file']
                ]
            ]                
           
        ];
        $response = $client->update($params);
        echo '<pre>', print_r($response, true) ,'</pre>';
    }
```

Is there a way to update the candidate's files directly with the new object without needing the fetch `$candidate['_source']['file']` so as to avoid overriding it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure -- use an [update script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) when you know which doc to update (using its `_id`):

```
POST candidates/_update/a23OcncBXBMGOH6pwXge
{
 "script": {
    "source": """
      if (ctx._source.containsKey('file')) {
        ctx._source.file.add(['filename':params.filename]); // adding a hash map -- could be any JSON primitive
      } else {
        ctx._source.file = [['filename':params.filename]]; // 1-member array
      }
    """,
    "params": {
      "filename": "abc"
    }
  } 
}
```

Alternatively, use the same script as above but under an [`_update_by_query` call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html). You can target that document (possible even multiple docs) **without ever fetching them**.

Comment: It worked well on kibana console. I'm having trouble converting it to php. Any idea on how to do it ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39162965/8160318

Comment: Unfortunately no, I already managed to make a basic script work. My issue is converting that if else statement. 
This is my attempt :    `'source' => ("ctx._source.containsKey('file')" ? "ctx._source.file.add(params.data)" : "ctx._source.file = [params.data]")`

Comment: The *whole* script should be inlined and included in quotes: `'source' => "ctx._source.containsKey('file') ? ctx._source.file.add(params.data) : ctx._source.file = [params.data]"` Does this throw an error?

Comment: Yes it still does. I found a working alternative though. I initialize the field "file" as an empty array. This way I only need to add to the existing array everytime : `'inline' => "ctx._source.file.add(params.data)"`. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Nice, glad to help!